# Magento 2 : Remove "Add new Address" Button in 2nd Step of Checkout Process for Customer Group

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, address

I created one customer group. How to disable(remove) "Add new Address" button in checkout process for customers who belonging to this group?

Comment: what you have done upto now? Please add your code here

Comment: Till now I created one customer group from admin. I am looking to the code but i am not getting

Comment: Please try something at your and if you get any problem than please add your code here

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so i'm afraid that it would require a module.
One that Extends the Magento/module-checkout/block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php and removes 'customer_register_address'(i think).

This is written with a very quick look at things. Do not pin me on that location.